# Is there a way to disable/enable the println! macro

Tags: rust

I have a program that makes liberal use of the `println!` macro. In hindsight I probably should have made use of a logging crate, as a lot of these `println!` statements I only want in the development environment.

Is there an easy way to "turn off' `println!`, for example with an environment variable? I use other macros in the code that I need to keep.

Comment: you can create your own wrapper macro for debug.

Comment: "In hindsight I probably should have made use of a logging crate" what are you waiting for ?

Comment: Add [log](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.11/log/) to your project, then: `sed -i.orig 's/println!/debug!/' src/*.rs` (or use IDE's search and replace function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with conditional compilation:

```rust
macro_rules! println {
    ($($rest:tt)*) => {
        #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
        std::println!($($rest)*)
    }
}
```

This only prints if `debug_assertions` are enabled. By default, they are enabled in debug builds and disabled in release builds. Alternatively, you can use a feature that can be toggled separately:

```rust
macro_rules! println {
    ($($rest:tt)*) => {
        #[cfg(feature = "stdout")]
        std::println!($($rest)*)
    }
}
```

```
# Cargo.toml

[features]
stdout = []
```

If you need an environment variable, you can do something like

```rust
macro_rules! println {
    ($($rest:tt)*) => {
        if std::env::var("DEBUG").is_ok() {
            std::println!($($rest)*);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there's a way to disable a macro through an envvar.

What you could do is replace `println!` itself with a macro_rules! basically reimplementing it (e.g. on top of write!) with environment-awareness.

But I'd recommend just biting the bullet and replacing it with something more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You typically want to forward all debugging/error messages to `stderr` stream via `eprintln!` instead of `stdout` via `println!`, which is used for useful output of your program.

From there on you can discard `stderr` stream:

in Windows

```
a.exe 2> nul
```

in Linux

```
./a 2> /dev/null
```